# Keyboard stuck in portrait IOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, landscape

I have 2 UIViewControllers A and B.I am presenting B to look like a dialog with UITextField and button.

When I click on the UITextField the keyboard shows always in portrait mode.

How I can fix it so show the keyboard in landscape as well?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the presentation to Over Full Screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable Landscape mode in Target>General>Deployment Info. also set "View controller based status bar appearance" to YES in your plist.

If you want to enable single view controller to support landscape mode you should follow 'Apple Guidelines" by implementing

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

Comment: My application support orientation and it can rotate.

I face this problem only when showing an UIViewcontroller over another one.